# React Native - Allow only Touchable/Pressable components as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to create a component `MyComponent` that receives a prop called `component` of type `React.ElementType`. My goal is to restrict the `component` prop to only Components that have a valid implementation for the `onPress` prop, so I just want to allow Pressable components like Button, Touchables, Pressables, etc.

How can I achieve this from typescript to get a proper declaration?
And how can I check if the component passed into the prop has an `onPress` implementation so I can throw an error if not??

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  // Allow only Components that have implementation
  // for onPress like TouchableOpacity,
  // TouchableWithoutFeedback or Pressable

  component: React.ElementType;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    component: Component,
    children
  } = props;

  // How to check if Component is a valid component that implements onPress??
  // So if not I can throw an error before render

  const myOnPress = () => {};

  return (
    <View>
      <Component onPress={myOnPress} />
      <View>{children}</View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have Typescript validate the prop at compile time, use generics to narrow down the ElementType like so:

```js
type Props = {
  component: React.ElementType<{onPress: (...args?: any[]) => void}>
}
```

You might want to make the type of arguments more or less specific, depending on your needs (eg by making the return value `any`).

Comment: Not aware of any way to check at runtime that the component type we pass in does actually accept onPress.